# Not able to set focus on the Dropdown component in Primereact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autofocus, primereact

I am trying to set focus on "Dropdown" component of the primereact but focus is not coming to the "Dropdown" component.

I have used autoFocus property as given in https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/dropdown . Then I tried to use react ref to set the focus.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdownautofocus-jko5d

Answer (score 2):

Focus on PrimeReact's `Dropdown` can be programmatically set using [DOM querySelector()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method. For example:

- Add an `id` to your `Dropdown`

  ```
   <Dropdown id="dropdown" ... />

   <Button onClick={onButtonClick} label="Set the focus" />
  ```
- In `onButtonClick` function use `querySelector` method to find and focus on `input` element of `Dropdown`

  ```
  const onButtonClick = () => {
     document.querySelector('#dropdown input').focus();
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus on PrimeReact's `Dropdown` using the [focusInputRef](https://primereact.org/dropdown/#api.Dropdown.props.focusInputRef) prop.  Here is an example:

- Create a ref:

  ```js
  const dropdownRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  ```
- In the onButtonClick function, use the ref to set focus:

  ```js
  const onButtonClick = () => {
      if (dropdownRef) dropdownRef.current?.focus();
  };
  ```
- Add the focusInputRef prop to the Dropdown:

  ```js
  <Dropdown focusInputRef={dropdownRef} ... />
  ```